# Undefined method username with twitter integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised) railscast to implement twitter signup using omniauth. After I am redirected from twitter I get this error in my user model.

```
undefined method `username=' for #<User:0x00000100d657a8>
```

This is the line in the model causing the problem:

```
 user.username = auth.info.nickname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your model `User` has an attribute `username` and corresponding column in the database?

If no, you should make a migration and add column `username`.

If yes, please post some more details and I will update the answer.

Comment: Ah, simple fix it was 'name' not 'username'. Thanks!

Comment: Its making me wait 6 more minutes ;)